# phpMyAdmin can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/myseql/mysql.sock'

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get phpMyAdmin working, connecting locally to mysql from Centos 6.3 running in VMWare Player.

mysqladmin -u root -p status
indicates that mysql is running.

Both my.cnf and config.inc.php point to socket `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock``.

I've tried 127.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin and localhost.0.0.1/phpMyAdmin.

In both cases I get the message:

```
#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)
```

Can anyone tell me what else to check?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the appropriate SELinux boolean to allow the web server to communicate with MySQL.

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect_db 1
```

Comment: That didn't do it, but I've confirmed that turning off SELinux altogether does.  Is there some other setting I'll need to change too?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment. Check the audit log `/var/log/audit/audit.log` and see what's logged when you attempt this access.